# Переписать код из js на vue.js

Tags: html, jquery, vue.js, шаблоны

Есть код на js. Вот [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/307536/). 
Как его написать на Vue?

```js
$('.select_box').click(function () {
  $(this).children('.options').toggleClass('open');
});
$('.field .option').click(function() {
  var num = $(this).text();
  num = parseInt(num);
  $(this).closest('.select_box').find('.input_val').val(num);
  $(this).closest('.select_box').find('.number_val').html(num);
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.field {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
.field-title {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
.select_box {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.values {
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.options {
  background-color: #f7d9d9;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.option {
  padding: 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.option:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.options.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="field">
    <label class="field-title">
      Номер 1
    </label>
    <div class="select_box">
      <div class="values">
        <span class="number_val">1</span>
        <input class="input_val" type="hidden" value="">
      </div>
      <ul class="options">
        <li class="option">1</li>
        <li class="option">2</li>
        <li class="option">3</li>
        <li class="option">4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label class="field-title">
      Номер 2
    </label>
    <div class="select_box">
      <div class="values">
        <span class="number_val">1</span>
        <input class="input_val" type="hidden" value="">
      </div>
      <ul class="options">
        <li class="option">1</li>
        <li class="option">2</li>
        <li class="option">3</li>
        <li class="option">4</li>
        <li class="option">5</li>
        <li class="option">6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Брать новый API и пробрасывать. С умом. Какой вопрос, такой и ответ.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно начать с создания приложения используя заготовку [Vue](http://jsfiddle.net/9m584k1e/25/):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    toggleClass: function(e) {
         $(e.currentTarget).children('.options').toggleClass('open');
    },
    fieldOption: function(e){
      var num = $(e.target).text();
  num = parseInt(num);
  $(e.target).closest('.select_box').find('.input_val').val(num);
  $(e.target).closest('.select_box').find('.number_val').html(num);
    }
    }
    
  });
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.field {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
.field-title {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
.select_box {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.values {
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.options {
  background-color: #f7d9d9;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.option {
  padding: 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.option:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.options.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="field">
    <label class="field-title">
      Номер 1
    </label>
    <div @click="toggleClass" class="select_box">
      <div class="values">
        <span class="number_val">1</span>
        <input class="input_val" type="hidden" value="">
      </div>
      <ul @click="fieldOption" class="options">
        <li class="option">1</li>
        <li class="option">2</li>
        <li class="option">3</li>
        <li class="option">4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label class="field-title">
      Номер 2
    </label>
    <div @click="toggleClass" class="select_box">
      <div class="values">
        <span class="number_val">1</span>
        <input class="input_val" type="hidden" value="">
      </div>
      <ul @click="fieldOption" class="options">
        <li class="option">1</li>
        <li class="option">2</li>
        <li class="option">3</li>
        <li class="option">4</li>
        <li class="option">5</li>
        <li class="option">6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```